# NSMutableAttributedStrings - objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsattributedstring, nsrange

I'm trying to add some fancy text to a label, but I've run into some problems with the NSMutableAttributedString class. I was trying to achieve four this: 1. Change font, 2. Underline range, 3. Change range color, 4. Superscript range.

This code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSMutableAttributedString* display = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                          initWithString:@"Hello world!"];
    NSUInteger length = [[display string]length] - 1;

    NSRange wholeRange = NSMakeRange(0, length);
    NSRange helloRange = NSMakeRange(0, 4);
    NSRange worldRange = NSMakeRange(6, length);

    NSFont* monoSpaced = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Menlo" 
                                         size:22.0];

    [display addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                    value:monoSpaced
                    range:wholeRange];

    [display addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName 
                    value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] 
                    range:helloRange];

    [display addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                    value:[NSColor greenColor]
                    range:helloRange];

    [display addAttribute:NSSuperscriptAttributeName 
                    value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] 
                    range:worldRange];

    //@synthesize textLabel; is in this file.
    [textLabel setAttributedStringValue:display];
}
```

Gives me this error:

```
NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds
```

Also, I tried messing around with the ranges, but became even more confused when I tried `NSRange worldRange = NSMakeRange(4, 5);`. I don't understand why that produces this: `Hell^o wor^ld!`, where the letters inside the ^s are superscripts.

`NSRange worldRange = NSMakeRange(6, 6);` produces the desired effect, `hello ^world!^`.

What the label looks like:
[image: outputtedText]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your length is too long on worldRange.  NSMakeRange takes two arguments, the start point and the **length**, not the start point and the end point.  That's probably why you are getting confused about both problems.

Comment: Yes! You're right. I've been trying to use it like a substring method! Ah, rookie mistake.

Answer (score 5):

`NSRange` has two values, the start index and the length of the range.

So if you're starting at index 6 and going `length` characters after that you're going past the end of the string, what you want is:

```
NSRange worldRange = NSMakeRange(6, length - 6);
```